# codeigniter csrf token regenerate by ajax. Error 403 forbidden the action you are requested not allowed

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

```
In Header.php

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var CFG = {
   url: '<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url');?>',
   token: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>'
  };
  $.ajaxSetup({
       beforeSend:function(jqXHR, Obj){
       Obj.data += '&token='+CFG.token;
   }
});
</script>
```

In Controller

```
    function get_master_law_tree_details(){
       $csrf = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
       log_message('debug','entity.get_master_law_tree_details - Starting');
       if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
          header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
          $this->tree_date = $this->ltm->get_master_law_tree_details($this->security->xss_clean($_POST));
          echo json_encode(array("data" => $this->tree_date,'token'=> $csrf)); 
       }
        log_message('debug','entity.get_master_law_tree_details - Ending');
     }
```

I have set token in header.php file which automatically add token in ajax call.